# Cant connect to MongoDB in Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions as the host for my MERN web app backend.
When I connect to MongoDB locally, it works and can run operations with the database. However, when I deployed to firebase functions, it failed to even connect to the database.

Code:

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const server = require('./server.js');
exports.api = functions.runWith({ memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 120 }).https.onRequest(server);
```

Part of server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const colors = require("colors");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const routes = require("./routes/routes.js");
const mongooseMethods = require("./database.js");
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });
mongooseMethods.connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// set up app
const app = express();
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold));
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use("/api", routes); // /api routes
module.exports = app;
```

routes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express.Router();
const testingApi = require('../controller/testing.js');
const authApi = require('../controller/auth.js');

// testing
app.get('/testing', testingApi.testing);

// user authentication
app.post('/user/register', authApi.createUser);

module.exports = app;
```

api/testing/ also works

database.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongooseMethods = {
    connectDB: async (url) => {
        try {
            console.log("Connecting to MongoDB")
            const connection = await mongoose.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
            console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${connection.connection.host}`.cyan.bold);
            return connection;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error: ${error.message}, Exiting`.red.bold);
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
module.exports = mongooseMethods;
```

auth.js

```
const User = require('../model/user.model.js');
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

let authenticationApi = {
    createUser: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            console.log("Creating");
            let newUser = new User({
                ...req.body
            })
            let result = await newUser.save();
            return res.status(200).json({ result: result });
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(400);
        }
    }

}

module.exports = authenticationApi;
```

The error I received when sending request to firebase is

```
2020-02-27T02:34:46.334044912Z D api: Function execution took 30970 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'
```

Yet it runs perfectly fine in local. I also don't see the console log "connected to MongoDB". I'm guessing that the problem occurs in database.js that it failed to connect to mongo at the first place yet I don't know how to solve.

I am using the paid plan in Firebase and the outbound networking should be fine.

p.s. this is my first time posting here. thanks for your time and I apologize in advance if i'm breaking any rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this to happen is that the architecture of Firebase Functions is not an actual server, but a serverless lambda-like endpoint. Since it cannot establish a lasting connection to the database, that it has to make a connection every time it received a request, the database sees this as spam and shut down further connection request from Firebase.

***Therefore, you simply cannot host a complete express app with intended lasting connection in Firebase Functions.***

More on that in this [article](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/lambda.html)

Comment: What is the alternative? Reconnect to the DB on every request?

Comment: Yes, you may read more on this [article](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/lambda.html).

Answer (score 0):

Listening on a port is not a valid operation in cloud functions:

```
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold));
```

Cloud Functions listens for you, using the URL that it was assigned, then delivers the request to your code.  When you pass your express app to `onRequest()`, that's all wired up for you.

I suggest starting with a stripped down, simplified version of an app just to gain experience about how things work, then add in more as you get comfortable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does that mean it is impossible to put an express app in GCF? or simply removing the line will do?

Comment: No, the documentation is clear that an express app is a valid argument. It just might not behave the way you want due to implied middleware.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps

Comment: Sorry, I was meant to ask if that's possible to put MERN app in GCF, that is if I can connect to mongodb in server.js and use it for the api or do I have to put connect to mongodb in every API function so that every time I call the API, it will reconnect for me. Thanks again for your time.
e.g.
createUser: 
// connect to db first
// do stuffs
// close connection

Comment: Your app should connect if not already connected from a previous invocation.